# Some questions regarding some statements of Shoenfield.

Tags: logic, foundations

Consider the system of arithmetic $\mathrm N$ found in Shoenfield's textbook *Mathematical Logic*:

N1. Sx$\neq$0,

N2. Sx=Sy$\rightarrow$x=y

N3.  x+0=x

N4.  x+Sy=S(x+y)

N5.  x$\cdot$0=0

N6.  x$\cdot$Sy=(x$\cdot$y)+x

N7.  $\lnot$(x$\lt$0)

N8.  x$\lt$Sy$\leftrightarrow$x$\lt$y $\lor$ x=y

N9.  x$\lt$y $\lor$ x=y $\lor$ y$\lt$x

Now N1-N6 is just a subtheory of Robinson arithmetic and N7-N9 can be  considered (?) inessential definitional axioms defining '$\lt$'. Note that the axiom $\forall$x(x$\ne$0$\rightarrow$$\exists$y(x=S(y))) of Robinson arithmetic was excluded from the list and for N1-N9 the universal quantifiers were (seemingly) excluded.

On page 51 of his book the following proof sketch of a finitary proof of the consistency of $\mathrm N$ can be found.  It goes as follows:

"By combining the fact that $\mathfrak N$ [the standard model of $\mathrm N$ (see pg. 23 for the description)--my comment] is a model of $\mathrm N$ with the completeness theorem, we get a proof of the consistency of $\mathrm N$.  We now indicate how we can convert this into a finitary proof of the consistency of $\mathrm N$.  First we replace the individuals of $\mathfrak N$ by concrete objects.  For this purpose, it suffices to replace the natural number $n$ by the expression containing $n$ strokes [and in so doing makes $\mathfrak N$ formulatable in the theory $TC$, making $TC$ the 'metatheory'--my comment].  Next we note that if we are given a variable-free term $\mathbf a$ or formula $\mathbf A$, we can actually compute $\mathfrak N$($\mathbf a$) or $\mathfrak N$($\mathbf A$).  It follows that in certain cases, we can give a finitary proof that an open formula $\mathbf A$ of $\mathrm L$($\mathrm N$) is valid in $\mathfrak N$.  In particular, we can prove that every instance of a non-logical axiom of $\mathrm N$ is valid in $\mathfrak N$.  Now it is clearly impossible to have open formulas $\mathbf A_1$,...,$\mathbf A_n$ such that $\mathbf A_1$,...,$\mathbf A_n$, and $\lnot$$\mathbf A_1$ $\lor$$\cdot$$\cdot$$\cdot$$\lor$$\lnot$$\mathbf A_n$ are all valid in $\mathfrak N$; so by the consistency theorem, $\mathrm N$ is consistent."

Futhermore, on pp. 131-2, one has the following theorems:

$\mathbf Church's Theorem$:  If $\mathrm T$ is a consistent extension of $\mathrm N$, then $\mathrm T$ is undecidable. (pg. 131)

$\mathbf Incompleteness$ $\mathrm Theorem$ ($\mathrm Goedel-Rosser$):  If $\mathrm T$ is a consistent extension of $\mathrm N$, then $\mathrm T$ is not complete. (pg. 132)

Question:  Is $\mathrm N$ just a version of Robinson arithmetic?

Question:  Are all recursive functions representable in $\mathrm N$?

Question:  If $\mathrm N$ is not equivalent to Robinson arithmetic, has it a name, and has it been studied (presumably it has)?

Comment: This is just Robinson arithmetic. The "missing" axiom you mention can be deduced from N7 - N9.

Comment: @BrianO:  Thanks.  So, Shoenfield's 'finitary' proof sketch of the consistency of $\mathrm N$ mentioned in my question holds (hope this question is not too silly --just needed to check....)?

Comment: Yes the finitary proof sketch works. Not a silly question, no. Note that Shoenfield chose axioms that are all open. It's easier to see that all of their concrete instances are valid in the standard model. it's also easier to see that the theory admits quantifier elimination :)

Comment: @BrianO:  Whence his comments on Hilbert's finitary vs. ideal distinction later on pg. 51?

Comment: I don't have my copy of Shoenfield with me so I can't check his discussion. But certainly that distinction is apropos. Hilbert's dichotomy was between "real" and "ideal" mathematical statements. "Real" ones, as per [Stanford online](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/hilbert-program/), "consists only of decidable, variable-free formulas. They are supposed to be 'directly capable of verification'—akin to propositions derived from laws of nature which can be checked by experiment".

Answer (score 1):

You can find (quite) it into George Boolos & John Burgess & Richard Jeffrey, [Computability and Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=nnAhAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA207) (5th ed - 2007), **Ch. 16.2 Minimal Arithmetic and Representability**, page 207-on for details.

They use the subsystem of *Robinson arithmetic* called *minimal arithmetic* to prove that :

> Every recursive function is representable in it.

---

*Note*

Instead of Shoenfield N9, they use :

> (Q9) $ \ \ 0 < y ↔ y \ne 0$
>
> (Q10) $ \ \ Sx < y ↔ (x < y \land y \ne Sx)$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Very helpful.  If I am understanding correctly (by Shoenfield's finitary consistency proof sketch quoted in my question) $\mathrm N$  (as well as $\mathrm Q$) is consistent.  From BrianO's comments  I understand that Robinson arithmetic admits elimination of quantifiers (so that 'real' arithmetical propositions can be transformed into 'ideal' propositions and back again, via the method described in "On the Infinite").  So now the following question presents itself:  Is the belief that Goedel's theorems destroyed Hilbert's Program flawed because

Comment: (cont.) the mathematical community confused Hilbert's conjectures about certain formal theories of arithmetic with his program?

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin - the discussion on [Hilbert's program](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/hilbert-program/) is still open; you can see some recent resources : Michael Detlefsen, [Hilbert's Program](https://books.google.it/books?id=VessBAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover) (1986) and Curtis Franks, [The Autonomy of Mathematical Knowledge: Hilbert's Program Revisited](https://books.google.it/books?id=cQteMYUb_2IC&pg=PA1) (2009). But the main problem remains; Hilbert conjectured to be able to use "finitistic" arithmetic (obviously consistent, because "checkable") to prove the consistency ... 1/2

Comment: ... of full f-o arithmetic (his system $Z$, today called $\mathsf {PA}$). Having proved this, to use (full) arithmetic to prove the consistency of *analysis* and then - presumibely - set theory. G's 2nd Incompleteness Th showed that we cannot "climb" on this "Hilbert's ladder" : starting from sub-systems of $\mathsf {PA}$ like Robinson or *minimal* arithmetic, those systems are not able to prove **their own** consistency and thus neither the consistency of $\mathsf {PA}$. 2/2

Comment: We can start, presumably, with Presburger arithmetic (which, of course, is well-known to be consistent, complete, and decidable--even though it, of course, cannot prove its own consistency), treat the missing multiplication axioms, which, added to it, gets you $PA$ as 'ideal propositions' (that way, one can use semantic methods to prove that the missing multiplication axioms are consistent with Presburger arithmetic --use the Hilbert-Bernays definition of  multiplication, i.e. for  $\mathfrak b$$\cdot$$\mathfrak a$ simply replace each occurrance of '|' in $\mathfrak a$

Comment: (cont.) with $\mathfrak b$ to prove this).  Contrariwise, use Shoenfield's finitary consistency proof for $\mathrm N$ (since $\mathrm N$ is just Robinson arithmetic, right?) to show  $\mathrm N$ is consistent, then show that $\mathrm N$+"Induction" is consistent via model-theoretic methods (after all, set theorists have been doing this sort of thing with $ZF$ for a very long time now--relatively speaking).  Regarding G1, since it is true but unprovable (G1, as has been stated in an answer to  a mathstackexchange question of mine, is an 'ideal proposition') it can be simply added as an

Comment: (cont.) axiom to $\mathrm N$.  Regarding G2, since Shoenfield has kindly provided us with a finitary consistency proof for $\mathrm N$, it is interesting, but irrelevant.  Whatever could be wrong with this picture, I wonder... :)

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin - but all the "gist" of Hilbert's Program is : do **not** rely on model theoretic concepts. After all, quite all of us (mathematicians and not) are fairly "happy" with the existence of *natural* numbers. Thus, if we believe that the "standard" structure $\mathbb N$ exists, then $\mathbb N \vDash \mathsf {PA}$ and the issue of *consistency* is obviously settled.

Comment: Note what is said in "On The Infinite", that the "extension by the addition of ideals is legitimate only if no contradiction is thereby brought about in the old, narrower domain, that is, if the relations that result for the old objects whenever the ideal objects are eliminated are valid in the old domain."  This suggests to me that Hilbert believed there was a consistent core theory to which "ideal propositions" could be consistently added--the ideal propositions were to be valid in the domain designated by the consistent core theory--certainly semantic.